# Customer support application using a Q&A dependency tree

Tags: help-desk

I'm look for an online app to build a helpdesk q&a section. 
But one that would lead the customer through the process.

Example:
*Do you have a mac or a pc?*

If answer is "pc" the next question would be:
*What version of windows do you have?*

And so on....

So it would kinda go through a predefined q&a tree. 
I've seen this on the internet multiple times, but don't know what to search for really.

Comment: How many different choice paths would there be? If less than 20, it might be enough to code directly in HTML. If more, a proper knowledge system would be nice indeed. By the way, I have a PC but not Windows ;-)

Comment: The idea is to continuously expand it. So something more generic than HTML would be great. I'll add Linux as an option :-)